# Backbone Models and Collections in ES6 aren't constructing correctly

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm using Backbone to create some models and a collection in ES6 as follows

```
import { Model, Collection } from 'backbone';

class Plant extends Model {
    defaults() {
        return {
            name: 'Not specified',
            height: 0
        }
    }
}

class Greenhouse extends Collection {
    constructor(options) {
        super(options);
        this.model = Plant;
    }
}

let plant1 = new Plant({ name: 'Rose' });
let plant2 = new Plant({ name: 'Daisy' });

let house = new Greenhouse([plant1, plant2]);

house.each(function(plant) {
    // Do something with plant here
});
```

But inside the house.each callback the plant object has none of the properties it should

for example `console.log(plant.get('name'))` is the default value 'Not specified'

There's not many working examples of Backbone in ES6 but from the few that exist it doesn't look like I'm doing anything different to those. Any pointers?

EDIT:

I've now also tried with non-ES6 and the same happens

```
let Plant = Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: "Not specified",
        height: 0
    }
});

var Greenhouse = Collection.extend({
    model: Plant
});
```

Comment: Why don't you use backbone's extend method?

Comment: As this seems to be the ES6 way to do it, am I incorrect?

Comment: Using ES6 extend is done here: https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc-backbone-es6/blob/gh-pages/js/todo-app.js

Answer (score 0):

Your import statement has a typo (Corrected in a [later revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/34980255/3)) :

```
import { Model, Collection } from 'backbone';
```

Besides that the rest of the snippets [seems to work](https://jsfiddle.net/ebqbr7xn/) as intended.

If it does not help please consider reproducing the issue in a fiddle.

Comment: I was paraphrasing my original code, the import statement is correct. I've tried to reproduce in a fiddle but getting Backbone to work in jsfiddle/codepen with ES6 is a nightmare

Comment: What exactly is the issue ? Can you provide specific versions of Backbone and Babel (assuming that is your transpiler) ? 

The link in my answer points to a fiddle where everything is same except the import.

Comment: I've figured out something at least. If I pass in an object, not an instance of the model, the collection turns it into a model when it's added. I want to be able to pass in a model, not pass in an object. Backbone version is 1.2.3

Comment: Once again your original code: `let house = new Greenhouse([plant1, plant2]);` seems to work just fine.

Comment: Yep, the only difference between this and my code is it's split over a few different files and bundled with Webpack. Instead of the attributes being saved inside models[x].attributes, they're in models[x].attributes.attributes

Comment: Solved it now, I had 'Backbone' instead of 'backbone' in my collection fine, I really appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the strangest thing I've ever had to fix.

I had `import { Collection } from 'Backbone'` instead of `backbone`

For some reason this didn't give any kind of error, I'm guessing something to do with it finding Backbone still but loading it under a different instance, maybe something to do with how webpack requires files